# Syntax Highlighter Jar

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting

I'm writing an IDE in Java and I'm looking for a library that will highlight the code for me. I've found plenty for javascript, but that wont do me any good. I'd love to write my own but I don't have the foggiest idea where to start. Are there any Java libraries out there?

Comment: I don't understand the close vote or downvote; please elaborate. The question is valid and trivially understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [jsyntaxpane](http://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/); it may be the easiest starting point rather than starting from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this library and it does the job pretty well: [RSyntaxTextArea](http://fifesoft.com/rsyntaxtextarea/)

Comment: That looks better at first glance.